# Wireless problems on an Ubuntu laptop

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm new to Linux, and I'm having trouble getting wifi set up on my laptop. 
The laptop is a Lenovo T430, I'm running the most recent version of ubuntu, and my wireless card is an Intel Advanced-N 6205. I installed a driver using the Windows Wireless Drivers app, but I still can't connect. I've seen other people online with similar problems, but none of their solutions have worked for me. I've tried toggling the wireless button on my computer, but airplane mode is stuck on. `rfkill unblock all` doesn't help either. I also checked the BIOS to see if wifi was enabled or not, and it is.

```
~$sudo rfkill list all outputs this:
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: After trying `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` `lshw -c net` changed to:
  `*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 60:67:20:3d:97:90
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:46 memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff`

### `lsmod` output:

`uas                    23159  0 
usb_storage            66545  1 uas
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                232283  0 
mac80211              652718  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               179412  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              494330  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    73089  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68937  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
rfcomm                 69509  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             446409  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_intel          30469  3 
intel_rapl             18783  0 
snd_hda_controller     31056  1 snd_hda_intel
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143590  0 
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   452043  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
uvcvideo               81073  0 
aesni_intel           152552  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 17393  0 
serio_raw              13483  0 
thinkpad_acpi          81027  1 
nvram                  14411  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
ndiswrapper           283985  0 
lpc_ich                21093  0 
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
i915                  905954  4 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
wmi                    19193  0 
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    79468  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 37047  0 
mei_me                 19696  0 
drm_kms_helper         61574  1 i915
drm                   311018  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
parport_pc             32741  0 
video                  20128  1 i915
mac_hid                13227  0 
mei                    87875  1 mei_me
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
e1000e                226396  0 
sdhci_pci              23301  0 
sdhci                  43685  1 sdhci_pci
psmouse               106561  0 
ahci                   34062  3 
ptp                    19395  1 e1000e
libahci                32424  1 ahci
pps_core               19382  1 ptp`

Comment: Without a Linux Driver using ndiswrapper for Cards is a good thing. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: I just read through these and I don't think the driver is the problem anymore. It says it's hard blocked, but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

What windows driver did you use `ndiswrapper -l` that card is supported in the kernel.  If there isn't a wireless switch do `echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf` and reboot to see if it is enabled.  Then I will help to get the kernel drivers going again

Edit: to remove the ndiswrapper version 
`sudo ndiswrapper -r netwsw00`
Reboot and post the results of `rfkill list all` and `lshw -c net`

Edit
[image: ThinkPad T430 pic] Is that a wifi switch between #1 and #8 in the bottom picture(right side view), does moving the switch change `rfkill list all` results?

`echo "blacklist ndiswrapper" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf`

reboot and see if the block exists
and we can remove ideapad.conf `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf`

Comment: ndiswrapper -l outputs:  
`netwsw00 : driver installed  
    device (8086:0085) present (alternate driver: iwlwifi)`  
I tried your suggestion, but there's no change yet.

Comment: `rfkill list all` outputs the same thing as in my original question, and lshw outputs this (sorry, I don't know how to format):   

  `*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff`

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and see if the results from `lshw -c net` changed and also add results to your question from `lsmod`

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I dismantled my T430 (running Ubuntu 19.10 LTS) for cleaning purposes, and in the process, something must have happened that triggered the wireless capabilities to stop working.

After much research and messing with different commands, I verified that the wireless card WAS being picked up by the computer, and it was on. However, upon doing `rfkill list all` I discovered that my Wireless LAN was hard blocked. This meant that something hardware-wise was interrupting.

I remembered that there is a small switch on the back-right side of the laptop, near the SD card slot that hardware-switches wireless connectivity. The switch was on, so I SHOULD have been getting internet, but I tried flicking it to the opposite side, which of course changed nothing, but then returning it back to ON (which shows green by the left side of the switch) turned wifi on right away and I'm back up and running.

So, my solution recommendation is try messing with that hardware switch a bit if you run into this issue. It fixed the problem for me.